# how to retrieve data from SPARQL endpoint in json format bulit on visual studio 2010

Tags: .net, json, rdf, sparql

i have an app which retrieves data from endpoint:http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/snorql/, connection is made there,query is sent and results received.
How do i receive the data in JSON format,the endpoint has the option to send results in this format,default I am getting RDF triples.
I m using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the tools you are using should not matter much.

the sparql endpoint at `http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/sparql`  returns json if you send an `output` parameter with the value `json`, as in:

```
curl "http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/sparql?query=SELECT+DISTINCT+*+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+10&output=json"
```

[run query](http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/sparql?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?s%20?p%20?o%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&output=json)